# exporting an array inside a hashtable to CSV without blank rows

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a hashtable containing arrays of strings as values such as

```
Name                      Value
----                      -----
ID1                       {SN1,IN1}
ID2                       {SN2,IN2}
ID3                       {SN3,IN3}
ID4                       {SN4,IN4}        
...                       ...
```

with `SN#` and `IN#` being strings.

I want to export this hashtable to a CSV file with this format:

```
 SN | IN
---------
SN1 | IN1
SN2 | IN2
SN3 | IN3
SN4 | IN4
```

... and so on.

so I used

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'SN' = $_.Value[0]
        'IN' = $_.Value[1]
    }
} | Select-Object SN, IN | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

but now the output looks like

```
 SN | IN
---------
SN1 | IN1
SN2 | 
    | 
SN3 | IN2
SN4 | IN3
```

... and so on with blank rows.

so when I tried to debug, i printed out the dictionary values when i typed in

```
$ht.values.get(0)
```

I got

```
SN1
SN2

SN3
SN4
```

and

```
$ht.values.get(1)
```

gave me

```
IN1
IN2


IN3
IN4
```

where it would give blank lines in between values.
But i print out the values in a regular forloop with a counter $n,
such as

```
$ht.values.get(0).get($n)
$ht.values.get(1).get($n)
```

I don't get the blank lines.

When I convert to Json, I get

```
{"ID1": [
             "SN1",
             "IN1\r\n"
        ],
{"ID2": [
             "SN2",
             "IN2\r\n"
        ],
{"ID3": [
             "SN3",
             "IN3\r\n"
        ],
{"ID4": [
             "SN4",
             "IN4\r\n"
        ]
}
```

How can i skip these blank lines when exporting to a csv file?

Comment: ```$ht.Values.ForEach{$_ -join ','} | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header SN, IN | Export-Csv output.csv```

Comment: Your data is not what you claim it is. Please show the output of `$ht | ConvertTo-Json`.

Comment: I just updated my question with the json result you wanted! @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried replicating the error you see but I don't get the same results.
I suspect that it may have something to do with your arrays, but it is hard to know since I cannot see the source of your data.

This is my test replication:

```
#Array made our of string pairs
$Array1 = ("SN1","IN1")
$Array2 = ("SN2","IN2")
$Array3 = ("SN3","IN3")
$Array4 = ("SN4","IN4")

#Hashtable with the string arrays
$ht = @{
    'ID1' = $Array1
    'ID2' = $Array2
    'ID3' = $Array3
    'ID4' = $Array4  
}
```

Getting the values from the hash also looks as expected:

```
$ht.values.get(0)
SN3
SN2
SN4
SN1

$ht.values.get(1) 
IN3
IN2
IN4
IN1
```

Could it be that your source data has "mismatched" array data compared to what you expect of the key parings?

If the data is indeed correct, a ConvertTo-Json should look like this:

```
$ht | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "ID3":  [
                "SN3",
                "IN3"
            ],
    "ID2":  [
                "SN2",
                "IN2"
            ],
    "ID4":  [
                "SN4",
                "IN4"
            ],
    "ID1":  [
                "SN1",
                "IN1"
```

**Edit1**
Seeing your output now you can see that you have escape characters in your IN code block. If you check the [Powershell Escape Character Syntax](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) you will see that you add a **Carriage return + New line**

So there are \r\n in your dataset and that is why your output gets scrambled around to new lines.

**Edit2**
Adding a replace for the values should work.

I am unsure if you need this:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'SN' = $_.Value[0].replace("`n","").replace("`r","")
        'IN' = $_.Value[1].replace("`n","").replace("`r","")
    }
} | Select-Object SN, IN | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Or this:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'SN' = $_.Value[0].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        'IN' = $_.Value[1].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
    }
} | Select-Object SN, IN | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: no the data source isn't mismatched. i thought of it and hand checked it before. thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Could you try and convert your hashtable to json and show us the result like @ansgar-wiechers suggests?

Comment: I just updated my question with the json result you wanted!

Comment: Just updated my explanation. Your dataset contains escape characters that mess up everything :)

Comment: thank you for your fast reply! do you know how i can get rid of \r\n's??

Comment: do you know how i can get rid of \r\n's? @HenrikStanleyMortensen

Comment: You should be able to do it with a replace, I have updated the answer to reflect this, I am however not sure if it should be with the return or the \ character, try each and see if it works.

Comment: Escape in PowerShell is `\``.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently your `IN` fields have trailing newlines that seem to mess up your data import. Trim them before exporting the data and everything should be fine:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'SN' = $_.Value[0]
        'IN' = $_.Value[1].Trim()
    }
} | Select-Object SN, IN | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: As a side-note, the `Select-Object` is unnecessary if the type of `New-Object` changes to `pscustomobject`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The `Select-Object` is for ordering the fields. Without it the column order would be `IN,SN`. I could've used the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator instead of `New-Object`, which implicitly uses an ordered hashtable, but then the code would only work in PowerShell v3 and newer. As for the italics: I used a HTML fragment. Click "edit" to see.

Comment: Good point. I had it in my mind he was working with a hashtable which isn't ordered by default